# Custom pagination or Other

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, repeater

i am confused about 2 way to display my data from db table
first way is to load all my data in pageload using listview with its built in page which allow me to navigate pages without page load each time
second way to use Repeater with custom Pagination which load number of record in each page (10 record per page)

say i have 200 record : 
is it better to load them at once at page load
or
load them 10 by 10

in real life what is fast and light to my web app.

Comment: it`s usually a good idea to use Repeater in web applications, to minimize waiting time for user.

Comment: In the end, it is all about the size of your data and how fast you can get it to the user.  Loading them 10 at a time seems like it would be a really irritating customer experience (constant paging).  For 200 records, you might be okay not paging (although it is getting around the max that I would do without paging).  Usually the best approach is to set it up for paging at a decent number (say 50) and then if your site expands to have 20000 data rows you are not running into as many performance issues.  You could also make the page size a variable somewhere so that you can easily change it.

Comment: thank  u @Vladimir  , i get from ur reply that u prefer repeater without paging which mean loading all data at once

Comment: @MBentley i said 10 as example not the number :) ,  but i get it , ur reply was helpful .

Comment: usually pagination become usefull when you have to deal with heavy data or numerous items.

Comment: i realy do not know when it consider heavy data in wep app in real life , actually i am desktop app developer :) ,  so most of my work was in LAN environment , and dont know how it will be in wep app work as a service . what about datatable contains 300 row with 8 columns is this heavy data or what . @Vladimir

Comment: @Vladimir sorry for annoying you ... how is repeater minimize time for user in web app rather than listview.. explain or refer to any link plz

Comment: @Emad Ahmed no problem, 300 items with the 8 properties should not be a problem without pagination, *but* if it would grow to 5000 rows then you might face internet latencies

Comment: @Vladimir thanks 4 ur patience